# Is there any way to reset the level progression?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For example, if I start a game at level 1, and use the console to advance the sneak skill all the way to 100 with `player.advskill sneak <huge number>`, is there any way to stop the game from forcing me to level up when I enter the skills menu?

Comment: You are a pro cheater, sir!

Answer (score 4):

The `advskill` command will count towards the character level up. To get your sneak skill up to 100 without triggering level ups, use the `modav` command instead to directly alter the skill:

> player.modav sneak 100

This adds a +/- for the number. So it'll add 100 to whatever sneak currently is. Alternatively use the `setav` command:

> player.setAV [actor value] [#]

To set it to exactly whatever value you'd like, although I'm sure there are some types of upper/lower bounds. Also, the commands are not case sensitive.

For a list of values you can change, see [Actor Values](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices).

Comment: The problem I have with `setav` is that it doesnt seem to save.

Comment: @JoethePerson What about forceAV?

Answer (score 1):

This is impossibe to have skill maxed without earning level as far as I know. Skill system is way to connected with character developement and earning levels to change something like that.

Comment: Is it better now @SevenSidedDie ?